# JAML4 - make: *** No rule to make target `clean'. Stop

Tags: c++, c, makefile, build

I am trying to the given code for the Jam L4 circuit board but get the error:

```
10:44:46 **** Clean-only build of configuration mbedTLS for project STM32L4xx-Nucleo ****
make clean 
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.

10:44:47 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 750ms)
```

and this in the error window:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'STM32L4xx-Nucleo'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

When I try and build the project. I have ensured that the make file is named correctly "Makefile".

Below is some of the code that is inside the Makefile related to clean.

```
.SILENT:

.PHONY: all check test clean

all: $(APPS)

$(DEP):
    $(MAKE) -C ../library
```

and

```
clean:
ifndef WINDOWS
    rm -f $(APPS) *.c
else
    del /Q /F *.c *.exe
endif

check: $(APPS)
    perl scripts/run-test-suites.pl
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is your Makefile split ?

Comment: @Zelnes Could you expand on this please, what do you mean by split?

Comment: What do you see if you just invoke `make -f Makefile clean` at a command prompt?  Does that work?

Comment: I entered the command into CMD window in its designated location, and go this response:

`'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Was this what you mean by enter into a CMD window? @G.M.

Comment: @L.Full I mean why is the code presented in 2 parts. Are they in 2 different files ?

Comment: @Zelnes not they are two snippets from the same file, would you like me to upload the full Makefile?

Comment: @L.Full No need. Your error with @G.M's solution means that the path where `make` is placed is not in your `PATH` variable. Try to find where it is located, and place yourself in the Makefile's directory, and then run `<full_path_of_make> -f Makefile clean`

Comment: `C:\Users\lFull\Downloads\Cloud-JAM-L4-AzureIoTHub-master (3)\Cloud-JAM-L4-AzureIoTHub-master\Middlewares\Third_Parties\mbedtls>make -f Makefile clean` Tried this but I get the same response @Zelnes

Comment: Currently trying to follow this tutorial and have followed step by step

Comment: https://catalog.azureiotsolutions.com/details?title=Cloud_JAM-L4&source=null

Comment: I think you didn't do what I wanted you to do. First, locate `make`, get the full path. Then, `cd` (or `dir` for Windows) into the makefile's directory. And then, call `make` by using the full path. For example : `dir C:\Users\Dev` and `C:\Users\Download\make -f Makefile clean`, if we suppose that you have `C:\Users\Dev\Makefile` and `C:\Users\Download\make`

Comment: When I search for make in C:\ there are multiple results, is there a specific make should I try and run, the downloaded content from the tutorial does not have a make inside it. The downloaded content only has Makefiles.@Zelnes

Comment: Have noticed that I am receiving a error notification: Failed to register URL "http://localhost:3984/" for site "Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot" application "/". Error description: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (0x800700b7)

Would this be causing the bot framework emulator to be blank?

Comment: The path you list to the 'make' function has a space.  So the path must be enclosed in quotes,  otherwise the 'shell' thinks it is two separate commands